# Python PyFPDF text wrapping with indentation

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I have one small issue when generating a PDF report with PyFPDF. If I can fix this, my project is done, so any quick fix is highly desirable, even if it's messy.

I need a combination of indentation and text wrapping, but my approaches thus far are not compatible. I indent lines with 8 tab characters (\t), 16 for two levels of indentation. I am printing the lines in a multi_cell to make sure they wrap to the next line. However, when the text wraps, it obviously doesn't preserve the tab characters from the beginning.

[image: description]

I can't seem to figure out how to place the multi_cell more to the right, or at a specific x coordinate, so I had to use the multiple \t characters. Here's a code sample below:

```
for d in currentDiagnoses:
    pdf.set_font("Arial", size = 9, style = 'B')
    pdf.multi_cell(0, 5, "- " + d.name, 0, 'L')
    pdf.set_font("Arial", size = 9, style = '')
    for i in d.items:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            pdf.multi_cell(0, 5, "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t= " + i[0], 0, 'L')
            for subi in i:
                if subi == i[0]:
                    continue
                pdf.multi_cell(0, 5, "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t- " + subi, 0, 'L')
        else:
            pdf.multi_cell(0, 5, "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t= " + i, 0, 'L')\
```

Code TL;DR: For each diagnosis object, print the name of the diagnosis. Then, print each criteria in the diagnosis indented once (8 tabs). If the item itself is a list, print the first item of that list at one indentation and the remaining items at two indentations (16 tabs).

Hopefully this isn't too confusing. We're trying to automate patient report generation and this is the final step before we can go live.

Comment: Try, if you could move `.multicell(...` to the right, doing a `self.cell(10)` or `.set_x(x: float)` before.

Comment: Wow, and with that, I am finished! Thanks much @stovfl

Comment: Update your Question and show your solution.